# What is cause of this error "Exiting due to error while processing commit log during" in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Any sstable tool I run results in this. The commitlog file that it complains about does not even exist.

How do I fix this ? Connecting with a client seems to work fine to run queries etc.,

```
> Exiting due to error while processing commit log during
> initialization. org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /somedir/servers/testcass/var/commitlog/CommitLog-4-1502836118644.log
> (Permission denied)
>         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:177)
> ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.freshSegment(CommitLogSegment.java:119)
> ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentManager$1.runMayThrow(CommitLogSegmentManager.java:119)
> ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>         at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
> [apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /somedir/servers/testcass/var/commitlog/CommitLog-4-1502836118644.log
> (Permission denied)
>         at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>         at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>         at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>         at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegment.<init>(CommitLogSegment.java:155)
> ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.13.jar:2.1.13]
```

Comment: can you include `ls -la /somedir/servers/testcass/var/commitlog`  and the user your running C* with?

Comment: it seems like user permission issue for directory /somedir/servers/testcass/var/commitlog/. Please update necessary permission of file modification for user running Cassandra